# Flutter: what is correct way to override core constants?

Tags: flutter

Example: if I want to override a constant in `flutter\lib\src\gestures\constants.dart`, what is correct way to do it.

Answer (score -1):

AFAIK, you can not override a constant. And you should not. That is the point. If you want to change a variable later, then you should not define it as a const or final.

Comment: I know I should not define a const if want change. But what I'm asking is about core constant. Problem is if I directly change the file, after upgrading has to change again. I want to find a better way to change it.

Comment: Ok, I did not realize that you mentioned about flutter/lib. You can change it in there. We are doing it. But don't forget to change again when you upgrade Flutter.